# Product sorting order in the shopping cart

Tags: shopping-cart, sort, ordering

What do you think is the best way to sort products in the shopping cart: newest added on top or at the bottom?

Especially on the mobile version of the website, I think that newest on top will give the user more assurance that the latest product was really added to the cart.

Does anybody know if there has been some research done on this topic before, that was published on the web? I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

probably any answer to this question will be inaccurate or overgeneralized.  **Specific individuals often use, and value, a shopping cart's contents in different ways.**. They will make different assumptions.  What is a 'correct' and 'natural' sort order for one person *will seem broken to another.*

You'll lose people from a marketing funnel, and a data analyst will develop a few models (for sort) to test, for optimizing checkout or other on-site transactions.

Get data, model behaviors, and have the app default (individualize) the sort method based on which type of user you think this is.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with New Alexandria re: run some testing, but if you want to just get something out - by default I see most carts organized by order of added items - first item at top > most recent added at bottom.

If you want to give the customer reassurance that something was added to cart, I would suggest exploring Toast messages and animation of your cart icon (movement, enlargement, number badge & increase)

Comment: I noticed, that on the four biggest e commerce websites Amazon, AliBaba, eBay and Walmart the cart ordering is in the opposite direction, newest products are added on top and I am wondering why. I have a feeling that this way it feels more natural for the user. I am wondering what could be the benefit of the sorting order when newest items are added at the bottom. I don't see any. I personally would like to see what I have recently added on top. I will definitely run some testing. Thanks